# Why colors of image are changing depending of it's size?

Tags: html, image, browser, colors

I have a logo in a PNG file. When I put it on a website in this way:

```
<img src="logo.png" />
```

everything is fine and the colors are as they should be.

But when I try to resize it - colors are changing.
I.e. this way:

```
<img src="logo.png" style="height: 75%; width: 75%;" />
```

or this way:

```
<img src="logo.png" style="height: 100px; width: 150px;" />
```

Every time the colors are different depending of the size of image and every time they are ligter than the origin ones.

The logo is quite simple and it contains only 2 colors.

I have checked it with some other images and there is the same problem.
It also exists in every browser (Firefox, IE, Chrome, Opera).

What can be done in order to remain origin colors of image while it's size is being changed?

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at the image it can be hard to tell exactly. However, here are a few things to look for:

1. Check your encoding. More than likely this would be the cause to color changing issues. Perhaps you used a buggy encoder and the image data is misaligned. That situation could cause weird glitches that are universal across browsers.
2. It could be natural aliasing. When an image is resized to a lower resolution there's a loss of detail. So for example, if a 100x100 image has a black horizontal line of 1px in the center and is then resized to 50%, either the line will disappear, or it will become lighter. That sounds similar to what you described.
3. Make sure you're using the right encoding for the file. I've come across images in the past that have file format that doesn't match with the encoding. This is unlikely to cause issues since file extensions are mainly used as a filter and not a definition for decoding.